# Extract Quarter from financial year as true or false

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables. I need to extract Quarter as true or false. Financial year starts from Oct. So Q1=Oct-Dec, Q2= Jan-Mar, Q3=Apr-Jun, Q4= Jul-Sept. Also I need to find if it is previous week as true or false. Week starts from Sunday. Here is a query which has been considered Q1= Jan-Mar and so on, but I need to consider Q1= Oct-Dec and so on.

select (CASE
WHEN (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER("FY20"), "FY", "") AS INT64) + 2000 = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AND (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER("Q2"), "Q", "") AS INT64) = EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE)) THEN true
ELSE
false
END
) AS FYQuarterToDate,

Please see input and output tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I need to consider Q1= Oct-Dec and so on ...

You can just simply shift date with 3 months to get proper quarter number as in below example

```
FORMAT('Q%i', EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)))
```

above gives you QN as per following rule -  Q1=Oct-Dec, Q2= Jan-Mar, Q3=Apr-Jun, Q4= Jul-Sept

Comment: @ Mikhali, Thanks for your help. so where I need to change in my code for the quarter. also, how can i find the current week, previous week.

Comment: I think you should replace `EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE)` with `EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH))`. as of week - your question has no any details about this and also on SO we usually expect one question at a time  - so I suggest you post new separate question regarding week :o)

Comment: @ Mikhali, Thanks for your help. It works fine now. I'll create another one for the week.

Answer (score 2):

Another slightly more performant way is

```
MOD(EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE), 4) + 1
```

That's because `MOD` and `+1` are faster to execute than `DATE_ADD(INTERVAL MONTH)`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. This query gives me 4, that means is it Q4. According to my question, current month is Q4.